# Display connected to Intel Graphics instead of Nvidia

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I don't know that much about computers but I recently saw that my Display is connected to Intel(R) UHD Graphics. I have a gaming laptop with and RTX 2060 and I felt that it was underperforming, could it be possible this is the reason why? Also, in NVIDIA settings I have the processor as my RTX 2060 but PhysX is connected to Intel Graphics, does that influence my FPS in any way ?

Laptop model: MSI GL63 9SEK

NVIDIA:

[image: NVIDIA screenshot]

Settings:

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: You’re reading the chart wrong; PhysX is pointing at the GeForce GPU. Intel GPUs cannot do PhysX. // Please provide your laptop’s exact make and model.

Comment: Its an MSI GL63 9SEK

Comment: “PhysX is connected to Intel Graphics, does that influence my FPS in any way?” - Tour screenshot does not indicate that.  PhysX is a Nvidia technology not an Intel one.  According to your screenshot it’s connected to the Nvidia GPU not the Intel GPU

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound all I want to know is if the Display is connected to Intel(R) UHD Graphics is a reason why my games have really low FPS considering I have a good graphics card.

Comment: Your laptop display is connected to the Intel GPU but that doesn’t matter.  Software is still able to use the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Then what could be the reason I have really low FPS on games with low settings ? I followed a tutorial on NVIDIA 3D settings so I could get more FPS but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop has [NVIDIA Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus). It is a technology that allows you to use an energy-efficient GPU for day-to-day work while being able to seamlessly switch to a powerful dedicated GPU for gaming or other demanding tasks.

Usually, the built-in logic is good enough at detecting when to use the dedicated GPU. Sometimes you may want to override this behavior. You can do this on a case-by-case basis in a program’s context menu:

[image: program context menu]

(It’s in German for whatever reason, but I think you’ll get the gist.)

The last option will bring up the NVIDIA control panel, where you can add a program and change the GPU it should use. This is especially useful for programs where you can’t bring up the context menu like this. Like games in Steam or the like.

Some games show in their options menu which GPU is active.

In Optimus laptops, the integrated display is always connected to the low-power GPU. Otherwise, the dedicated GPU could never switch off. When the dedicated GPU is used, it sends the finished image to the low-power GPU for displaying it.

Some laptops, like yours, also have connectors that are going directly to the dedicated GPU. In your case that’s the Mini-DisplayPort connector and the HDMI connector.

If you feel performance is too low, you can take a look in Task Manager’s
“Performance” tab. Just start a game, do stuff and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> over to see which GPU was busy.

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal that my cpu is that busy?

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61LfT.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180498)